# XDocument descendants

Tags: c#, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?> 
<kdd>
<Table>
    <robel ID="1">
        <groof NAME="GOBS-1">
            <sintal ID="A">Cynthia1</sintal>
            <sintal ID="B">Sylvia2</sintal>
            <sintal ID="C">Sylvia3</sintal>
            <sintal ID="D">Sylvia4</sintal>
        </groof>
        <groof NAME="GOBS-2">
            <sintal ID="A">Cynthia1</sintal>
            <sintal ID="B">Cynthia2</sintal>
            <sintal ID="C">Cynthia3</sintal>
            <sintal ID="D">Cynthia4</sintal>
        </groof>
        <groof NAME="GOBS-3">
            <sintal ID="A">Daniella1</sintal>
            <sintal ID="B">Daniella2</sintal>
            <sintal ID="C">Daniella3</sintal>
            <sintal ID="D">Daniella4</sintal>
        </groof>
    </robel>
</Table> 
</kdd>
```

I would like to get GOBS-2's Cynthia1. Note there is another Cynthia1 from GOBS-1

```
foreach (XElement element in doc.Descendants("groof"))
                {
                    string mmname = element.Attribute("NAME").Value.ToString();

                        if (mmname == "GOBS-2")
                        {
                            bool found = false; 
                            foreach (XElement element1 in doc.Descendants("sintal"))
                            {

                                if (found == false)
                                {
                                    string CurrentValue = (string)element1;
                                    if ("Cynthia1" == CurrentValue)
                                    {
                                        try
                                        {
                                            //do something
                                            found = true;
                                        }
                                        catch (Exception e)
                                        {
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

the problem is , after it finds Cynthia1 from Gobs-2, the loop goes up to Gobs-1.
I think there is a problem with the second foreach  for sintal
perhaps I should use different thing.
I want that after it finds Gobs-2's sintal it just stops looking. it seems the 2 foreach are not related. running on each own

Answer (score 15):

> I would like to get GOBS-2's Cynthia1

You can use Linq to get there more precisely:

```
XElement cynthia = doc
    .Descendants("groof")
    .Where(g => g.Attribute("NAME").Value == "GOBS-2")
    .Elements("sintal")
    .Where(s => s.Value == "Cynthia1")  // or Attribute("ID") == "A"
    .Single();
```

Comment: Great answer +1  You could move the where into the single to shorten `.Single(s => s.Value == "Cynthia2");`

Comment: Yes, I know. But I don't always find that clearer. In this case it's a toss up, I'll leave it this way. Showing all the steps separately.

Answer (score 2):

You have a mistake in the inner foreach loop, you should be iterating over `element.Descendants("sintal")` not `doc.Descendants("sintal")`

```
foreach (XElement element in doc.Descendants("groof"))
{
    string mmname = element.Attribute("NAME").Value.ToString();

    if (mmname == "GOBS-2")
    {
        bool found = false; 
        foreach (XElement element1 in element.Descendants("sintal"))
        {

            if (found == false)
            {
                string CurrentValue = (string)element1;
                if ("Cynthia1" == CurrentValue)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //do something
                        found = true;
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The reason you are getting the `sintal` element from the first `groof` tag is that `doc.Descendants("sintal")` looks for the first sintal tag in the document, not the parent node you previously selected.